# SonarQube fails to start due to findbugs and fbcontrib

Tags: plugins, sonarqube, findbugs

I'm upgrading from Sonar 3.1.1 to SonarQube 4.0.  I have the sonar-fb-contrib-plugin-1.2.jar file in my extensions/plugins directory.  The startup fails with the following message:

```
2013.11.12 15:10:17 INFO  org.sonar.INFO  Install plugins done: 197 ms
2013.11.12 15:10:17 ERROR o.s.s.p.PlatformLifecycleListener  Fail to start server
org.sonar.api.utils.SonarException: Fail to extend the plugin findbugs for fbcontrib
```

My understanding is that findbugs comes bundled with SonarQube (I can see the jar file under bundled-plugins).  I'm not sure what the problem is here - it doesn't look like this works out of the box as it did for 3.1.1

Comment: what's the version of the sonar-findbugs-plugin? all plugins in the java ecosystem should be at least 1.4 when sonar >= 3.7.3

Comment: Thanks for your response - I see the following in my SonarQube directory:

Comment: Sorry - return = post - the version is ./lib/bundled-plugins/sonar-findbugs-plugin-1.4.jar which is what comes with SonarQube 4.0.  I put sonar-fb-contrib-plugin-1.2.jar in place (I previously had 1.1 when I was running sonar 3.1.1 - thanks again!

Comment: Move the fbcontrib plugin away, then restart sonar so it comes up and updates the database; then put the plugin back and restart. Take backups

Comment: Wow...thanks!!  It worked!  I could have sworn I initially started the app and went through the DB update without the plugins in place.  But, I just moved that one jar off, started it up, it said my DB was already up-to-date, shut it down, put the jar back in place and restarted...and it came up fine!  Thanks so much for your input - you unblocked my entire team!

Comment: happy to help, and welcome to stackoverflow; you will find a lot of expertise on many areas around the sdlc in this site. fell free to accept and upvote my answer below

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a similar issue while upgrading from 3.6 to 3.7.3; the fbcontrib-plugin depends on the findbugs-plugin which is part of the sonar java-ecosystem.

In this case it is safe (and [documented](http://docs.codehaus.org/display/SONAR/Upgrading#Upgrading-HowtoUpgrade), point 6) to take a backup of the database and of the extensions directory before updating; then update and restart sonar having moved away any external contribution plugin, so that sonar can manage the update and come up back successfully. Another good tip is to not overwrite new configuration files with the old ones, instead manually editing them to bring over the old settings.

Then, add the plugins back and restart again; happy static analysis.